# Bulding a grid with available elements and forms Popper Js and what?

Tags: javascript, jquery, popper.js

I got stuck.

Planning to build a page with a grid which show you avaialble information about each of the square.

As example, in real estate niche, let's take this example.

Having 'a lot' of lands divided by parcels, and once you hover on each parcel, it gives you different details and the form.

I'm stuck at how to build and render the lot page on the web?

Few of the libraries I'm planning to use are Popper JS.

[something similar i would like to build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpVzC.png)

Example from the screenshot: https://anonym.to/?https://crminvermid.com/sistemas_active/crm/if/indexBase.php?id=G08xwkfJW8P52&rd=&rg=&clvde=zXDV09Lh7zD6

Comment: Sorry but this is not a good fit for Stack Overflow. Please visit the [help] and take the [tour] for more information on what makes a good question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: thank you. i was a bit confused on what technology they use for the grid. i do apreciate.